# Combine three UPDATE statements into one statement

Tags: mysql

This is my update statement below

```
UPDATE esys.sysacd 
SET sacd_menu_id='M3,M4,A1,E0,H1'
WHERE sacd_id_no='40005'
AND sacd_co_no='60'
AND sacd_proj_cde='9'; 

UPDATE esys.sysacd 
SET sacd_menu_id='B2,M3,A1,E0,H1'
WHERE sacd_id_no='20048'
AND sacd_co_no='60'
AND sacd_proj_cde='9'; 

UPDATE esys.sysacd 
SET sacd_menu_id='M3,M4,A1,E0,H1'
WHERE sacd_id_no='170209'
AND sacd_co_no='60'
AND sacd_proj_cde='9';
```

Can I combine my update statement? Means I only want to do one update only and not like what I did. Because I only need to add the sacd_menu_id with H1. Any idea?

Comment: Comma-separated values in SQL tables are generally a bad idea. You should normalize your schema.

Comment: Please don't edit titles to include "solved". Accepting an answer marks it automatically as solved.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Im newbie here

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` expression.

```
UPDATE esys.sysacd
SET sacd_menu_id = CONCAT(sacd_menu_id, ',H1')
WHERE sacid_id_no IN ('40005', '20048', '170209')
AND sacd_co_no = '60'
AND sacd_proj_cde = '9'
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can only add H1 into sacd_menu_id? For example, sacd_menu_id='M3,M4,A1,E0' (in my database). I want to add only H1 into the current database without the need writing back sacd_menu_id='M3,M4,A1,E0' .

Comment: `sacd_menu_id = CONCAT(sacd_menu_id, ',H1')`